# Android Studio 3.0.1 commenting out lines in Android.mk

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, android.mk

Is it not possible to comment out lines in the top-level Android.mk file of an Android Studio NDK project?

If I remove the Hello.mk line shown below, I get no errors. If I add a # then I get the error "This file is not part of the project."

How can I temporarily remove this line (i.e. comment it out) ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some weird reason Android Studio tries to treat your **Android.mk** as a C++ source. You can safely ignore this and many other warnings that AS displays.

OTOH, you can safely delete the line, instead of adding `#` in front: Android Studio keeps local history of the files that you edit thorough it; so, you can easily restore any changes to this file when you need that.

Comment: I tend to comment out lines when I want to try something out. In this case I wanted to try building SQLite on its own without the Hello.mk but I can always undo/redo.

Comment: If you believe that you discovered a bug in Android Studio, and can reproduce it, don't hesitate to [file a ticket](https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html)!

Comment: Now that I know I how to optionally specify 'targets' (and possibly comment them out within the build.gradle file), I can exclude targets from the build there instead.

Comment: Bug reported filed! :-)

Comment: Hi @AlexCohn , Can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903357/android-studio-ndk-linker-error-undefined-reference-to-cv-outputarray-outpu